# Random Page after Chapter/Before Mainmatter

Tags: chapters, scrbook, blank-page

I get a weird blank page in front of my `mainmatter`. I tried for hours to get it removed in different ways, but I do not seem to find my mistake.

My `.tex`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, 12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
    
    \frontmatter
    
    \chapter{Abbrevation}
    \blindtext
    
    \mainmatter
    
    %%%% Put chapters here
    /\chapter{Chapter}
    \blindtext
    
\end{document}
```

**EDIT: As you can easily see, my problem is created by a Typo in front of `\chapter`. The `/` is easily missed.**

The weird result I do not want:

[image: The weird result I do not want]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  It is generally helpful to trim out the excess so that you end up with a minimal working example.  In this case, however, I assume the blank page is because `oneside` tells TeX that the main matter should always begin on an odd numbered page.  Try `twoside` instead.

Comment: @Teepeemm IIRC it is the other way round. Such blank pages are expected with `twoside` but not with `oneside`. Therefore, a minimal working example is crucial here.

Comment: Thanks for the Responses. I tried recreating my error with a minimal approach, somehow, i wasnt really abled to. I tried to track down the reason for this by removing package by package. This led to an unrelated error message which did let me find the reason for my mishap: I had an `/` in front of the `\Chapter` following `\mainmatter`. I will edit the question anyways to a more simple version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can easily see, my problem is created by a Typo in front of `\chapter`. The / is easily missed.